# sharing large datatable in the memory?

Tags: asp.net, memory-management, shared-libraries, static-methods

I have a few table frequently used by my website. for example, largest one is a location table which is holding massive static data. So anytime users come over my website, they do search for within these locations. It holds around 1.5 million rows. I have sized this table using memory profiler and it is nearly 500mb in the memory. eventually I have a few more static tables those I need to access very quickly and they are static. at the end my memory dump gets up to 1,5 gb memory usage. which is not a problem for me while I have a powerful server with a lot of memory available.
but when I raise that question, senior developers and architectures are telling me that I should review my project because a process shouldn't occupy that much memory. But I need quick access, I don't want to query my DB every time. I need response under 1 sec. Thats why memory looks like the way for me. Is there any better advise ?

I am using asp.net and ms SQL 2008. at the moment Framework 4.0 but soon will be 4.5. IIS 7.5 on my webserver.

I appreciate for your help.
thanks.

Comment: The most scalable way is using the database, 1.5M rows is nothing. It would never take more than a second.

Comment: If you have access to a decent DBA put your heads together and see if you can't come up with a reasonable set of Indexes - with appropriate DB tuning you should get to the desired performance threshold of 1-2 seconds fairly easily. I agree with Tim Schmelter.

Comment: I am sorry.  I did a bad mistake. I need indeed under 1 sec. 0,1, 0,2 sec etc. That's I am able to get using memory but not DB.

Answer (score 1):

The process definitely shouldn't hold this memory itself. The http server might want to have the process running several (thousand) times in parallel and than you'll be in trouble. Now that's *not* to say the data shouldn't be in memory. All Google data is in memory most of the time. You just have to be careful how you load them.

1. If the database server is any good (it should be), it will actually keep the data in memory if they are frequently accessed or if you set appropriate caching policy. That should give you decent performance without having to do much work or any weird tricks at all.
2. You could use [memcached](http://memcached.org/) (that is the Google way).
3. You could have the data in file with custom format designed for quick access in your particular use-case and access it via memory-mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping large set of static data is not recommended in production environments. As i see in your scenario your data set can be normalized and manage minimum number of initial data set.

Other way is using a design pattern like builder to construct data set only what is needed on demand.

By going to such approach you can avoid keeping unnecessary data set in your memory. and load what you want when you want .  Basic idea of builder is available on [1].

[1].http://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html